# mysql substract multiples columns values and put the result in an empty column

Tags: mysql

im a newbie in mysql using phpmyadmin. all i want is the following:

```
  table  planning
  id int (11)
  actual_mileage int (11)
  base_filter_change int (11)
  last_filter_change int (11)
  next_filter_change int (11)
```

what i need is to get automatically

```
  substraction1 -> (actual_mileage int - last_filter_change int)= results
```

then

```
   substraction2 -> (base_filter_change - results)= endresults
```

Finally the result is thrown to the field

```
    next-_filter_change
```

thats all.thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
update planning
set next_filter_change = (base_filter_change - (actual_mileage - last_filter_change)
```

Comment: Wao! you're an angel man.  thanks! you don't say how it can be done automatiquely. i mean each time we enter a new mileage it should be updated (calculated automatiquely). briefly, WHERE to store the query?..thanks another time.     NB: you should add parenthese at the end of your code. so as people who would read this issue don't make mistake when inserting sql code.